# Using sed to Replace Portion of String Containing Slashes and Special Characters

Tags: bash, sed

I have a config like:

```
{
  "taskdb": "sqlite+taskdb:///taskdb.db",
  "projectdb": "sqlite+projectdb:///projectdb.db",
  "resultdb": "sqlite+resultdb:///resultdb.db",
  "message_queue": "redis://:tFjlvTZ%V4#&YtGl7JEa2l#&@127.0.0.1:6379/0",
}
```

I want to change the Redis password via a shell script.
Seems it usually using `sed` to do such work, but I find something hard to cope with.

First, I try to match `redis://:tFjlvTZ%V4#&YtGl7JEa2l#&@`

I have tried the following, but they don't work:

```
1. `sed -i 's/^redis:\/\/:.+@$/{&}/g' config.json`
2. `sed -i 's#^redis://:.+@$#{&}#g' config.json`
3. `sed -i 's/redis:\/\/:.+@/{&}/g' config.json`
```

What I really want to match is `tFjlvTZ%V4#&YtGl7JEa2l#&`and replace it with a new password. But I even can't match the row.

Comment: @Hemang that's just a test code , I only want to replace the password

Comment: @anubhava Sorry, I copy the real pasword....I just write the `{&}` for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -i 's#redis://:[^@]*#redis://:NEW_PASSWORD_HERE#g' config.json
```

If you don't want a `.bak` file:

```
sed -i '' 's#redis://:[^@]*#redis://:NEW_PASSWORD_HERE#g' config.json
```

We're basically searching for "any character that isn't an `@` sign" after `redis://:`, and replacing this whole leading string with `redis://:NEW_PASSWORD_HERE`.

Now, if you wanted to specifically match only a line that contained `message_queue`, you could do something like this as well:

```
sed -i '/message_queue/s#redis://:[^@]*#redis://:NEW_PASSWORD_HERE#g' config.json
```

**Edit**

As mentioned in the comments, if there's an `@` in the password (although I don't think the Redis connector would be able to parse it), we can use a different method of anchoring our match:

```
sed -i 's#redis://:.*\(@127\.0\.0\.1\)#redis://:NEW_PASSWORD_HERE@127.0.0.1#g' config.json
```

Or, with less redundant typing:

```
sed -i 's#\(redis://:\).*\(@127\.0\.0\.1\)#\1NEW_PASSWORD_HERE\2#g' config.json
```

`\1` and `\2` represent the two groups enclosed between `\(` and `\)`.

**Another Edit**

You mentioned in the comments that you expected `sed 's/redis:\/\/:.+@/{&}/g' config.json` to work since [Regex101 shows that it will](https://regex101.com/r/dA2lE1/1). However, Regex101 is using Perl-based regular expression engines, rather than POSIX-style regular expressions like `sed` uses. Additionally, without operating in "extended regex" mode, the `+` operator won't work in `sed`. This can present a challenge for portability, as the "extended regex mode" option differs on Linux (`-r`) and Mac OS X / BSD (`-E`). Unfortunately, I cannot find a regex testing tool similar to Regex101 for POSIX/ERE regular expressions.

Comment: Password may contain `@`, and could I just match the password and replace it?

Comment: I have a feeling that the `redis` connector you're using wouldn't be able to parse it with an `@` in the password. But, let me add an example that will work with `@`.

Comment: I think what I write`sed 's/redis:\/\/:.+@/{&}/g' config.json` is not wrong , regex is greed default, see https://regex101.com/r/dA2lE1/1. Why it would not work?

Comment: @will, yeah, I would have thought that an `@` in the password would have to be `%`-encoded in the redis: URL

Comment: See my edits; this now works for passwords with `@` in them. Regex101 is using Perl-Compatible Reguar Expressions, or PCRE. Sed uses "POSIX Regular Expressions" instead, which work a bit differently. Additionally, the `+` operator won't work in `sed` unless you're in extended-regex mode (`-r` or `-E`).

Comment: Just for the record: The first 2 code snippets will behave exactly same (`-i` & `-i''` are same). If there is .bak file generated, it will be generated for both snippets or none. `sed` on my machine would not generate .bak in either case.

Comment: Well they're not actually the same. I swear on some machines I've had `-i` create `.bak` files automatically, and `-i''` prevents this. On my Mac OS X BSD-sed, I actually get a syntax error if I specify `-i` with no backup extension, and `-i''` works perfectly.  With GNU `sed` 4.2.2, it seems to not create backup files by default with `-i` and no backup extension. `-i''` seems safest for scripting and portability.

Comment: `-i` & `-i''` are both parsed by your shell (`bash`?), before passing to `sed` & most (if not all) shells will parse it in same way. If that is the case, `-i`, `-i''`, `'-i'` are all same. So for all these cases, `sed` will receive the same parameters. Did you mean `-i"''"`? This will pass `-i''` to `sed` command. (I am aware that OSX `sed` asks you for the `.bak` & fails otherwise) Or does OSX `bash` treat `-i` & `-i''` differently?

Comment: Actually, it's `-i ''` that works on Mac OS X. 

`$ sed -i 's/test/blah/g' test.txt`
`sed: 1: "test.txt": undefined label 'est.txt'`

`$ sed -i '' 's/test/blah/g' test.txt`
`$`

I realize that it is processed by the shell, but I believe '' will be passed as an empty string argument. If I run `./myprogram '' '' 123`, `123` would be considered the third argument.

Answer (score 2):

On first glance I see a few problems with your expression:

The first is that you are using `^` and `$` to delimit the beginning and end of the string you want to match but those operators mean that you want to match the beginning and end of a line respectively. Since your string to match is in the middle of the line you need to get rid of them.

The second is that standard sed doesn't support the `+` operator. If you are using GNU `sed` you can give it the `-r` option to get extended regex notation. Or you can just use the `*` operator which will probably be good enough for you here.

Lastly, I don't know what you're going for with the `{&}` in the replacement text. Shouldn't that just be the replacement password?

Comment: Thank you, google say sed support regex which make me write that regex.The 3 line is just to test if sed worked.

Comment: @Mithril There are, confusingly, a number of variants of regular expression syntax. It's worth taking some care to be sure you are familiar with the dialect you're using.

Answer (score 2):

By default, `sed` does not recognize `+` as a metacharacter.  If you have GNU `sed`, add `-r` to make it recognize it; with BSD `sed`, you'd use `-E` instead.  (However, we can infer that you're using GNU `sed` since BSD `sed` requires a suffix for the `-i` option and you're not providing one.)  But the `.+` notation is too greedy for safety.  You really want one or more 'not-`@`' characters.  The `g` modifier is superfluous (but otherwise harmless); you've only ever got one URL on a line in the config file.  That's written:

```
sed 's/redis:\/\/:[^@]\{1,\}@/{&}/' config.json
```

That should work with any version of `sed`.  You could also use:

```
sed -r 's%redis://:[^@]+@%{&}%' config.json
```

which is specific to GNU `sed` because of the `-r`.  Changing the delimiter from slash to percent is doable in all versions of `sed`.

Of course, if you want to replace the password component with a new value, and as long as the new value does not contain any percent symbols, you can use:

```
sed -r 's%(redis://:)[^@]+@%\1new-password@%' config.json
```

If you need to work with the password in a variable, use double quotes instead of single quotes:

```
sed -r "s%(redis://:)[^@]+@%\1${new_password}@%" config.json
```

Also note that you really shouldn't use the `-i` option until you've got your script working.  Granted, if you work on a copy of the data file it isn't the end of the world, but it's usually better to add the overwriting only when you're confident that the script edits the file the way you want it to.